# Передать множество переменных методом POSTставить в вышеуказанный код

Tags: php, post

Здравствуйте.

Итак, есть некое множество переменных var1, var2, ... varN которые передаются в обработчик методом POST. Число N всегда разное, но до передачи оно уже известно.

Нужно в обработчике выполнить простой цикл

```
for ($x=1; $x<$_POST['N']; $x++) 
{ echo $_POST['varN']; }
```

Как сделать, не соображу. Как подставить в вышеуказанный код порядковый номер переменной? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

PS Собрать массив из этого множества, передать, и потом разобрать - по ряду причин, к сожалению, тут не подойдёт.

Comment: `$_POST['var' . $x]`?

Comment: да! спасибо вам))

Comment: Кстати, если `var1`, `var2`, ... `varN` заменить на `var[]`,  то в `$_POST['var']` окажется массив.